# Bash script to convert a date and time column to unix timestamp in .csv

Tags: bash, unix, csv

I am trying to create a script to convert two columns in a .csv file which are date and time into unix timestamps. So i need to get the date and time column from each row, convert it and insert it into an additional column at the end containing the timestamp.

Could anyone help me? So far i have discovered the unix command to convert any give time and date to unixstamp:

```
date -d "2011/11/25 10:00:00" "+%s"
1322215200
```

I have no experience with bash scripting could anyone get me started?

Examples of my columns and rows:

```
Columns: Date, Time, 
Row 1: 25/10/2011, 10:54:36,
Row 2: 25/10/2011, 11:15:17,
Row 3: 26/10/2011, 01:04:39,
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Can you include few example rows of your csv file?

Comment: Sure thing, added it into question, cheers

Comment: Conversion only without parsing part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990949/convert-date-time-string-to-unix-timestamp-in-bash-command

Answer (score 7):

You don't provide an exerpt from your csv-file, so I'm using this one:

```
[foo.csv]
2011/11/25;12:00:00
2010/11/25;13:00:00
2009/11/25;19:00:00
```

Here's one way to solve your problem:

```
$ cat foo.csv | while read line ; do echo $line\;$(date -d "${line//;/ }" "+%s") ; done
2011/11/25;12:00:00;1322218800
2010/11/25;13:00:00;1290686400
2009/11/25;19:00:00;1259172000
```

(**EDIT**: Removed an uneccessary variable.)

(**EDIT2**: Altered the date command so the script actually works.)

Comment: Thanks for you help: I have put this into a shell script as follow: #!/ltd/bin/bash

cat myfile.csv | while read line ; do t=$(echo $line | tr ',' ' '); echo $line\;$(date -d "$t" "+%s") ; done I got the error illegal option --d when i ran it? Also am i right to assume i need to replace ';' with ',' as i have a comma seperated file not semi colon sperated?

Comment: Run it as a oneliner and test it prior putting it in a script-file to see if it works for you. And yes, you need to change `';'` to `','` if you use semicolon separated csv-file.

Comment: @bos you can shorten the loop part of the while loop with `echo ${line}\;$(date -d "${line//;/ }" +'%s');` No need for echo and tr to get the right date string. So this could be done inplace.

Comment: You can remove the $t variable as well since it's not used. I don't know why I left it there. Removing it and editing the post.

Comment: What exactly does the `"$t"` after `date -d`?

Comment: `"$t"` is a forgotten left-over variable of a previous script.

Answer (score 2):

this should do the job:

```
 awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "}{t=$1" "$2; "date -d \""t"\"  +%s"|getline d; print $1,$2,d}' yourCSV.csv
```

**note**

you didn't give any example. and you mentioned **csv**, so I assume that the column separator in your file should be "comma".

**test**

```
kent$  echo "2011/11/25, 10:00:00"|awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "}{t=$1" "$2; "date -d \""t"\"  +%s"|getline d; print $1,$2,d}'
2011/11/25, 10:00:00, 1322211600
```

Answer (score 2):

Now two imporvements:

First: No need for cat foo.csv, just stream that via < foo.csv into the while loop.

Second: No need for echo & tr to create the date stringformat. Just use bash internal pattern and substitute and do it inplace

```
while read line ; do echo ${line}\;$(date -d "${line//;/ }" +'%s'); done < foo.csv
```