# CSV column to Unix timestamp

Tags: csv, unix-timestamp

I have a column of TimeStamps which looks like this

2012-12-14 22:22:00

2012-12-14 21:55:00

2011-09-21 13:21:00

I would want to create another column OR replace this column which contains the Unix time-stamps of the respective datetime timestamps.

Comment: And the question is? You have to use some tool, for example a programming language or database query language and look how to convert date/time values in there...

Comment: Can I use bash commands to that directly ?

Comment: Sure, bash is a programming language in the end.

Comment: Take this as a starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267595/bash-script-to-convert-a-date-and-time-column-to-unix-timestamp-in-csv