# Adding timestamps to csv-file in bash

Tags: bash, unix, csv, timestamp

My problem is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267595/bash-script-to-convert-a-date-and-time-column-to-unix-timestamp-in-csv). I basically want to add a column of timestamps to a .csv-file with bash. I'm using this script:

```
cat foo.csv | while read line ; do echo $line\;$(date -d "$t" "+%s") ; done
```

and this .csv-file (foo.csv):

```
2011-11-25  12:00:00
2010-11-25  13:00:00
2009-11-25  14:00:00
```

but instead of getting the expected output, I get an output like this:

```
2011-11-25,12:00:00;1400882400
2010-11-25,13:00:00;1400882400
2009-11-25,14:00:00;1400882400
```

Anybody who knows what might be wrong?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: In Bos' answer to the question that I linked to, I'm supposed to get this: 2011/11/25;12:00:00;1322218800
2010/11/25;13:00:00;1290686400
2009/11/25;19:00:00;1259172000

Comment: `man date` would show you that `%s` is 'number of seconds since the epoch;'. Try +`%Y/%m/%d %H:%M%S`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need parsing the date from incoming file and printing it timestamp use this:

```
date --date="$line" "+%s"
```

Comment: This I know, but it doesn't really help me with the strange output from the .csv-file.

Comment: If you problem is wrong formatting of the first line than you have to format it too as suggested in shellter comment.

date --date="2011-11-25  12:00:00" "+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S; %s"

And you probable want to leave the echo out.

If your problem are the wrong timestamp its because you are not providing correct date to the function ($t instead of $line in your command).

Comment: Got it. The magic happened when I combined your knowledge with shellter's and f4m8's from the other thread. This code does the job: cat foo.csv | while read line ; do echo $line\,$(date -d "${line//,/ }" "+%s") ; done Thank you!